# orderby() and distinct() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, distinct

The following line doesn't work as distinct() doesn't give ordered output.

```
var context= new BatchEntities();//Entity model
var practices = (from p in context.EMSCAN_BATCH orderby  p.PRACTICE select p.PRACTICE).Distinct();
```

Tried this:

```
var practices = (from p in context.EMSCAN_BATCH
                             select p.PRACTICE).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x.PRACTICE);
```

This gives error that string doesn't contain definition for 'PRACTICE'....
Also tried this:

```
 var practices =(from p in context.EMSCAN_BATCH
                select new
                {
                  p.PRACTICE
                }).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x.PRACTICE);
```

This gives wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `PRACTICE` from `OrderBy`

```
var practices = (from p in context.EMSCAN_BATCH
                 select p.PRACTICE).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like this:

```
var practices = context.EMSCAN_BATCH.SELECT(m => m.PRACTICE).Distinct().OrderBy(m => m.PRACTICE);
```